# I have makemigrations error, how can I solve it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
from turtle import mode
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in 
import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install tkinter

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: you can explicitly put version, In your case try  `sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk`

Answer (score 0):

Use brew to install tkinter:

```
brew install python-tk
```